# Canvas Javascript Looping

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to loop my animation, but no matter what I do, it won't loop. I'm pretty new to canvas, javascript and code in general.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("fabrication");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var background = new Image();
background.src = 
"C:/Users/dylan/Desktop/ProjectTwo/Images/fabricationbackground.jpg";
background.onload = function(){
}


//Loading all of my canvas

var posi =[];
posi[1] = 20;
posi[2] = 20;
var dx=10;
var dy=10;
var ballRadius = 4;

//Variables for drawing a ball and it's movement

function drawballleft(){


posi =xy(posi[1],posi[2])
}
function xy(x,y){
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    var newpos=[];
    newpos[1]= x +dx;
        newpos[2]= y +dy;
    return newpos;

//Drawing the ball, making it move off canvas.

if (newpos[1] > canvas.width) {
newpos[1] = 20;
}
if (newpos[2] > canvas.height) {
newpos[2] = 20;
}
//If statement to detect if the ball moves off the canvas, to make it return to original spot

}
setInterval(drawballleft, 20);
//Looping the function
```

Please let me know if I've done something wrong, I really want to learn what I'm doing here. The ball is supposed to go off the canvas, and loop back onto itself, but it goes off the canvas and ends.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try setting newpos values using .push() like so newpos.push(20) and remember that array indexes start at 0 not 1.

Comment: Don't use `file://`. Use a real, static server.  Most IDE have this feature built in.  You could also use the `http-server` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes to your code.

First I am using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/requestanimationframe.shtml

Second I am not using an image because I didn't want to run into a CORS issue. But you can put your background image back.

I simplified your `posi` array to use indexes `0` and `1` instead of `1` and `2` to clean up how you create your array.

I moved your `return` from before the two `if`s to after so the ball will move back to the left or top when it goes off the side. *I think that was the real problem you were seeing*

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("fabrication");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Loading all of my canvas

var posi =[20,20];
var dx=10;
var dy=10;
var ballRadius = 4;

//Variables for drawing a ball and it's movement

function drawballleft(){
  posi = xy(posi[0],posi[1])
  requestAnimationFrame(drawballleft);
}

function xy(x,y){
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,300);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  var newpos=[x+dx,y+dy];

    //Drawing the ball, making it move off canvas.

  if (newpos[0] > canvas.width) {
    newpos[0] = 20;
  }
  if (newpos[1] > canvas.height) {
    newpos[1] = 20;
  }
  //If statement to detect if the ball moves off the canvas, to make it return to original spot

  return newpos;
}

requestAnimationFrame(drawballleft);
```

```css
canvas {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="300" id="fabrication"></canvas>
```

Comment: It works in the code snippet like it's intended to, but it doesn't seem to work on my canvas - The one ball moves on its own, off the canvas, then stops and doesn't appear again.

Comment: did you move the `return` to after the to `if` statements? If not then the ball will fly off the edge of your canvas and never be seen again.

Comment: I sorted it! It loops amazingly, thank you! How do I make it appear in the same place every time, instead of looping throughout the canvas? I.e. appear in its first position, loop, etc.

Comment: If you want to have it always start at [0,0] then change your code in the `if` to set both `newpos[0]` and `newpos[1]` to `0` instead of only doing the one that went off the screen. If that is not what you mean then let me know exactly what you are after and I'll try to help.

Comment: I managed to sort it by removing the if statement for canvas.width, thereby setting canvas.height to newpos[0] = 0, and newpos[1] = 0. Thank you so much for your help - Now I have to mirror it, and I should be happy with it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

To make it all even simpler...
Use an external script for handling the canvas.

A really good one ;) :
https://github.com/GustavGenberg/handy-front-end#canvasjs

Include it with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/Canvas.js"></script>
```

Then it's this simple:

```
// Setup canvas
const canvas = new Canvas('my-canvas', 400, 300).start(function (ctx, handyObject, now) {

    // init
    handyObject.Ball = {};

    handyObject.Ball.position = { x: 20, y: 20 };
    handyObject.Ball.dx = 10;
    handyObject.Ball.dy = 10;
    handyObject.Ball.ballRadius = 4;

  });

// Update loop, runs before draw loop
canvas.on('update', function (handyObject, delta, now) {

    handyObject.Ball.position.x += handyObject.Ball.dx;
    handyObject.Ball.position.y += handyObject.Ball.dy;

    if(handyObject.Ball.position.x > canvas.width)
      handyObject.Ball.position.x = 20;

    if(handyObject.Ball.position.y > canvas.height)
      handyObject.Ball.position.y = 20;

});

// Draw loop
canvas.on('draw', function (ctx, handyObject, delta, now) {

    ctx.clear();

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.arc(handyObject.Ball.position.x, handyObject.Ball.position.y, handyObject.Ball.ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);

    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.closePath();

});
```

I restructured your code and used the external script, and now it looks much cleaner and easier to read and toubleshoot!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n7osvt7y/